# Copy/Yank entire Lisp form in Slime

Tags: emacs, lisp, slime

Is there a way to copy/yank a whole a form in Slime/Emacs?

For instance, if I have the following function:

```
(myfunc (lst)
    (myotherfunc lst))
```

I'd like to yank/copy:

```
(myotherfunc lst)
```

by issuing a keyboard shortcut when my cursor is at the opening or closing parenthesis for that form (at the point where Slime/Emacs does parenthesis matching).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my Emacs, function [`kill-sexp`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Expressions.html) is bound to <kbd>C-M-k</kbd>. That is, assuming the point is just before an opening delimiter of a *balanced expression*, press Control, Meta, and k at the same time.

This same command works in various other non-Lisp modes, such as killing brace-delimited blocks in a C-style mode, though the `kill-sexp` command may not be bound to the same keys.

Answer (score 14):

- <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd> (mark-sexp) to put the mark
  at the end of the sexp, then copy/yank
- <kbd>C-M-f</kbd> (forward-sexp) and <kbd>C-M-b</kbd> (backward-sexp) are useful to move forward and backward over a balanced expression

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching#toc2

Answer (score 4):

The emacs minor mode [ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) does this on normal kills 'C-k' by default.  I would certainly recommend it to any emacs+slime users.

Comment: Also worth mentioning here just as a reminder for anyone that doesn't know C-y will insert the line back into the buffer at the current cursor location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) and then you can press <kbd>n</kbd> which runs `lispy-new-copy` to copy

```
(myotherfunc lst)
```